# jQuery Mobile page does not show content until I Refresh

Tags: jquery-mobile, page-refresh

Why does my html page with two 'Mobile' pages inside have to be refreshed or have the little edges moved to show my map in this?  See [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DaddyMagic/j6tkn539/3/) or the code below:

I have a mobile page document (html) that has two jQuery Mobile pages.
1.  The landing page where you are asked to have your position known.
2.  The OpenLayers3 map page which takes your position and centers the map on it when opened.

My trouble is: the map will build and it will center on the position but does not render until after I resize refresh the 'map' edges or the browser window.  I suspect it has something to do with page events but am not sure.

Is there a property that I am missing?

Andy

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>MobilePg</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/css/ol.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src=" http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/build/ol.js"></script>

    <style>
        #myFooterPosit {
            color: gray;
        }
    </style>

    <script>
        var x, y;
        $(document).ready(function () {
            if (navigator.geolocation) {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
            }           
        });

        function showPosition(position) {
            var positThing = $('#myFooterPosit');

            positThing.text('lat: ' + position.coords.latitude + " : " + " long: " + position.coords.longitude);

            x = position.coords.latitude;
            y = position.coords.longitude;

        }


    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <script>
        $(document).on("pagebeforeshow", "#mapPage", function () {
            makeMap();
        })
    </script>
    <!-- Landing page Point of Entry-->
    <div data-role="page" id="homePage">
        <div data-role="header">
            <a href="#mapPage" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-icon-location ui-btn-icon-left">Map</a>

            <h1>Mbl Map Input</h1>
            <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-icon-search ui-btn-icon-left">Search</a>

        </div>
        <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
            <p>My Content..</p>
        </div>
        <div data-role="footer">
            <h1><span id="myFooterPosit"></span></h1>

        </div>
    </div>


    <!-- Map Page -->
    <script>
        function makeMap() {
            try {
                alert(x + " : " + y);
                var map = new ol.Map({
                    target: 'map',
                    layers: [
                    new ol.layer.Tile({
                        title: 'OSM',
                        type: 'base',
                        visible: true,
                        source: new ol.source.OSM()
                    })],
                    view: new ol.View({
                        center: ol.proj.transform([y, x], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
                        zoom: 14
                    })
                });
            } catch (e) {
                alert(e.message);
            }
        }
    </script>
    <div data-role="page" id="mapPage">
        <div data-role="header">
            <a href="#homePage" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-icon-home ui-btn-icon-left">Home</a>

            <h1>Map</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
            <div id="map" class="map" style="height:200px;"></div>
        </div>


        <div data-role="footer">
            <h1><span id="myFooterPosit"></h1>

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html
```

>

Comment: I am not sure if the fiddle is working or not from the link.  http://jsfiddle.net/DaddyMagic/j6tkn539/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the pagecontainer widget's show event:

http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecontainer/#event-show

> Updated **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/j6tkn539/8/)**

```
var x, y;

$(document).on("pagecreate","#homePage", function(){ 
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    }
});
$(document).on( "pagecontainershow", function( event, ui ) {
    if (ui.toPage.prop("id") == "mapPage"){
        makeMap();
    }
});

function showPosition(position) {
    var positThing = $('#myFooterPosit');
    positThing.text('lat: ' + position.coords.latitude + " : " + " long: " + position.coords.longitude);
    x = position.coords.latitude;
    y = position.coords.longitude;   
}

function makeMap() {
    try {
        var map = new ol.Map({
            target: 'map',
            layers: [
            new ol.layer.Tile({
                title: 'OSM',
                type: 'base',
                visible: true,
                source: new ol.source.OSM()
            })],
            view: new ol.View({
                center: ol.proj.transform([y, x], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
                zoom: 14
            })
        });
    } catch (e) {
        alert(e.message);
    }
}
```